# User doesn't see the comment delete icon

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments

[Here is a report](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1710/254) of a user who cannot delete their own comments.

- Using the full (not mobile) version of the web site
- Using two different browsers (Firefox and Chrome) on Windows
- Cannot see the on-hover icon which would allow them to delete their own comments
- Yet can see the on-hover icons which allow them to upvote or flag other users' comments

Comment: That account is not the result of a merge with a different account?

Comment: @rene That sounds like a good question, but SFAIK (I'm a volunteer moderator on that site) I don't know how to answer it, though I expect an SE employee would. It's happening even with *recent* comments, anyway.

Comment: Let's see if it's only design (i.e. missing icon) or actual server block. Please ask the user to use Chrome, browse to the site where he can't delete comments, click F12, go to Console tab, and paste this exact code: `$.post("http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/18688/vote/10", {"fkey": $("#fkey").val()});` then press ENTER. This code should cause [this comment](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/11355/is-the-k%C4%81l%C4%81ma-sutta-really-libertarian/11356?noredirect=1#comment18688_11356) to be deleted, and based on the result we'll know better how deep the bug goes.

Comment: **NOTE**: don't try it yourself, since you're a moderator there there's a good chance it will delete the comment as well. (but then you can undelete it)

Comment: We might as well create all kind of fancy scripts for mods to run though... don't be afraid, we can be trusted.....

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thank you; I'll ask the user to do that.

Comment: @rene Shadow doesn't have a diamond. :-/ But that little script is using the web site's public API, so what could possibly go wrong? :-)

Comment: *famous last words...*

Comment: @ChrisW no API here, just using direct command, which kind of mimics pressing the delete button. However, it's most likely possible to write script that will erase all comments on the site if run by moderator, since moderators get unlimited delete votes.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It looks like that script is posting a bit of JSON. The fact that it's to a very specific URL makes me think, "that looks legit". rene though has been trying to convince me that obeying you is foolish. Anyway I haven't run the command myself.

Comment: @ChrisW on meta I tend to troll a little bit more, [the script is safe to run](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3931923#3931923).

Comment: @rene Thank you, here comes the sun.

Comment: @ShadowWizard f12 and then where to I paste the code? There does not seem to be any obvious place to do so.

Comment: No wait. I've got it. And the response is: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/18688/vote/10. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://meta.stackexchange.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @Jayarava you first need to visit/load http://buddhism.stackexchange.com in a new tab and on that tab when all is loaded, hit F12, copy-paste the snippet again and hit enter.

Comment: @Jayarava Which web page was loaded in Chrome when you ran that command? I.e. were you looking at this page on `http://meta.stackexchange.com/` or the page at `http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/` or a page at `http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/`? It needs to be the latter, i.e. try the command while you're looking at a page from `http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/` for example [this page](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/11355/254).

Comment: Indeed, both @rene and Chris are right. Not sure it will work, but if not at least we'll have more info about the bug.

Comment: I was looking at the comment that was targeted. i.e http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/11355/is-the-k%C4%81l%C4%81ma-sutta-really-libertarian/11356?noredirect=1#comment18688_11356

Comment: @Jayarava The error message i.e. "Origin '**meta.stackexchange.com**'; is therefore not allowed access" implies that when you ran the script, it was running against a page from **this** `meta.stackexchange.com` site and not from the Buddhism site. Can you please try [this suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266030/user-doesnt-see-the-comment-delete-icon?noredirect=1#comment863253_266030) i.e. open `buddhism.stackexchange.com` in a new tab, and open the Developer tools window on that new tab, etc.?

Comment: OK. It worked that time. The comment on http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/11355/is-the-k%C4%81l%C4%81ma-sutta-really-libertarian/11356?noredirect=1#comment18688_11356 is now gone. And what's more I am now seeing the delete icon when I mouseover it - not when I mouseover the comment per se (which was the instruction) but only when I mouseover the icon itself - this confusion may be the solution to the problem. Apologies for any inconvenience. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Jayarava Thanks for the information. I'm glad you have at least found a work-around (i.e. mousing over the icon). IMO that's a bug (needing to mouse-over an invisible icon), and is not what I see (I can mouse over anywhere in the comment's text or in the comment's signature).

Comment: @ShadowWizard Please see new information above.

Comment: @Jayarava the color of the delete button is very light gray, so when on white background it might be hard to see, especially if there's light reflected on your screen. When hovering, it becomes red which is much more obvious. If you can try using some dark theme in your browser, I'm 99% sure you will suddenly see the delete icon just fine. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I posted [a screenshot of it here](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/1709/254) from my browser. Is that a good test, i.e. should he be able to see the icon on his screen, exactly as well as he can see the icon on my screenshot on his screen? Also he can see the flag-comment and upvote-comment icons which I guess (I haven't measured) are a similar shade of gray.

Comment: Yes, this is weird but I can't really think of anything else..

Comment: @Jayarava Will you try to continue to pursue this problem with Shadow Wizard, or have you finished with it now you found a way that works? I don't know but I'm guessing that Shadow Wizard might want to tag this bug report as closed/inactive/finished, if and when nobody is working on it any more.

Comment: I'm happy as things stand. @ShadowWizard can close the big report.

Comment: I can't really close this by myself, I'm just an ordinary user. However I will flag this and ask to tag as [tag:status-norepro] since this issue is not happening to anyone else. /cc @Jayarava.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

In [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266030/user-doesnt-see-the-comment-delete-icon?noredirect=1#comment863186_266030), Shadow Wizard asks you to "click F12 and go to Console tab".

Using Chrome, after you press the <kbd>F12</kbd> key, Chrome will display a "Developer tools" window, of which the top-right corner has some icons which looks like this:

[image]

If you click on the first of those icons (i.e. the one which is shaped like `>_`) that opens (at the bottom of the Developer tools window) a so-called "Console" window which looks like this:

[image]

Please copy and paste the specified text into that window:

[image]

... position the cursor after the text, press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to run that command, and report when you've done that. Thanks!